# Draw abline outside of plot margins on one side only

Tags: r, plot, par

I'm working on an R plot that will be separated into two parts by a vertical line I'm creating with `abline()`.I would like that abline to go over the boundaries of my plot on one side only.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496684/how-to-draw-a-line-or-add-a-text-outside-of-the-plot-area-in-r#) helpful post about setting [par(xpd=)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html). However, I could not figure out how to get this command make the line go over the plot border on one side only, as outlined in the screenshot below.

- Is there a way to do this in base R? (Or do I have to rebuild the
  whole thing in ggplot etc?)
- I feel that the key might the differences between `figure region`,
  `device region`, etc. but was unable to really determine the difference
  between those. I looked at this
  [source](http://www.melissaclarkson.com/resources/R_guides/documents/figure_layout_Ver1.pdf)
  but at least for my plot those settings seem to amount to the same
  thing - it would be cool if anyone had some help here as well!

Here's my approach:

```
plot(100, 100)
par(xpd=TRUE)
abline(v=70, lty=3)
```

And what I get / want:

[image: My plot]

Any  help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lines`. Set limits of `y` as you want.

```
plot(100, 100)
par(xpd = TRUE)
lines(x = c(70,70), y = c(45, par('usr')[4]), lty = 2)
# par('usr') gives the 4 extremes of plot
# par('usr')[4] gives the extreme on top
```

Another option is to not mess with `xpd` and use `axis` instead. Use `tck` to define the length of line beyond the plot. `tck = -0.25` means the length is one fourth of the plot height towards bottom.

```
plot(100, 100)
par(xpd = FALSE) #Only because we made TRUE above 
abline(v = 70, lty = 2)
axis(1, at = 70, labels = NA, tck = -0.25, lty = 2)
```

Comment: this is a beautiful answer, thank you for your help!